# running liferay portlet on websphere application server 8.5.5

Tags: java, tomcat, websphere, liferay

I have developed a liferay portlet and tested it on tomcat. I have deployed the decorated war via websphere admin console.
I was able to start that under **application -> websphere enterprize application** section and the status was **started**.

When I open `http://localhost:9080/` I am not able to see that portlet in add->more portlet option in liferay.

Please help me how could I be able to deploy that properly. Is any configuration needed further?

Comment: you should look at running your portlet in websphere portal, or define a context root for your portlet war, and the portlet will run

Comment: I have already defined a context root e.g. /cont-root for the portlet and the portlet is visible under server -> Update Manager section in liferay. how that can be visible in add portlet section?

Comment: What does the Liferay log say? Liferay needs to "see" the portlet in order to make use of it, and if it doesn't pick up the portlet, you won't see it. Also, I hope that your "decorated war" means that this war file is what already went through Liferay's "deploy" folder - Websphere is not as automagic as tomcat with regards to installing new plugins

Comment: Thanks! I will see the logs and let you know

Comment: WOW! I resolved the problem by adding some **custom settings** in admin console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed the documentation: **https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen11-installing-liferay-on-websphere-80-0**.

and after starting liferay 6.1.20 ee ga2 on WAS successfully I have to add some settings in **servers>Server Types>websphere application server>** select my server (server1 in my case) **Server1>Process Definition>Java Virtual Matchine>Custom Properties**

Add New

```
    **application.mnemonic** value **tag**
    **applicationproperty.location** value **c\tools\liferay\portlet**
    **external.properties** value **portlet-local.properties**
    **liferay.environment** value **local**
    **server.name** value**$WAS-SERVER-NAME**
```

By adding these custom setting I am now able to deploy the maven built portlets and now those are visible into my liferay add > more  section